# Python/ Google OAuth2 ssl error

Tags: python, ssl, oauth-2.0

Working through [the python google OAuth2 API](https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/python/guide/aaa_oauth#step1_get_authorize_url) and am successfully receiving the redirect_uri with the code. I copy everything after "code=" in the returned URL and submit that to the step2.exchange(code) command but python shows the following error:

> File "C:\Python34\lib\ssl.py", line 810, in do_handshake
>       self._sslobj.do_handshake() ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed (_ssl.c:600)

My questions are as follows:

1.) What is the correct format for the code? Simply all charactors after "code=" in the returned url?

2.) What else could cause this error? I installed certifi 2015.04.28 as suggested elsewhere but this did not fix the problem.

3.) Any other suggestions to fix?

Code is as follows

```
from oauth2client.client import flow_from_clientsecrets

from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys



flow = flow_from_clientsecrets('C:\Python34\client_secrets.json',
                               scope='https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive',
                               redirect_uri='https://www.samtec.com)
auth_uri = flow.step1_get_authorize_url()



#open firefox, send auth_uri to the interwebs
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(auth_uri)

name=driver.find_element_by_name("Email")
name.send_keys("******")
name.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#wait 10 seconds for the page to load before proceeding
#driver.manage().timeouts().pageLoadTimeout(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
passw=driver.find_element_by_name("Passwd")
passw.send_keys("*******")
passw.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)


#wait for page to load, approve access token
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
allow=driver.find_element_by_id("submit_approve_access")
allow.send_keys(Keys.RETURN)

#get the URL returned to the browser, get the returned code
returnedURL=driver.current_url
if "=" in returnedURL:
    param, code = returnedURL.split("=",1)

##remove white space
code=code.strip()

##obtain he OAuth2 object/tokens
credentials = flow.step2_exchange(code) ##error occurs on this line
```

Using python 3.4.3

Thanks

Comment: Not sure of a fix but I tested your code with  `redirect_uri='http://localhost:80'` locally and it does work so there is nothing wrong in the code logic itself